# Strict aliasling warning on gcc 4.6.1 bug

Tags: c++, gcc, strict-aliasing

I'm trying to compile the following on gcc with `-pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wall -O2`

```
#include <iostream>

void reset_uint32(uint32_t* pi)
{
    char* c = (char*)(pi);
    uint16_t* j = (uint16_t*)(c); // warning?
    j[0] = 0;
    j[1] = 0;
}

void foo()
{
    uint32_t i = 1234;
    reset_uint32(&i);
}

int main() {
   foo();
}
```

But I don't see any strict aliasing warnings. I have also tried to enable

```
-fstrict-aliasing
-Wstrict-aliasing
```

but still no warnings. Is it this a bug?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. Why not just do `*pi = 0`?

Comment: @Pubby: Presumably this is just a contrived minimal test-case...

Comment: First, the aliasing rules allow conversions to and from `char *`. Secondly, g++ doesn't promise to warn, just says that it will try. If you change it to convert directly to `uint16_t` and have `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` it will give you a warning.

Comment: @Omnifarious: the strict aliasing rule allows aliased access through a `char*`, but doesn't allow 're-aliasing' to another type through that `char*` type (I hope what I wrote makes sense).  But for all I know, it might cause the warning to be disabled, intentionally or not.

Comment: @Omnifarious "_First, the aliasing rules allow conversions to and from `char *`._" First, the aliasing rules neither allow nor disallow any pointer conversions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Some time ago, the documentation for Wstrict-aliasing=2 promised to warn for all possible aliasing violations. I noticed pretty much what you're noticing now, which is that the aliasing violations went undetected when I added an intermediate conversion to/from void*. I reported that as a bug, the GCC folks decided that this was too complicated to warn for, and the documentation was changed to no longer promise to detect all violations. I'd say this is the expected behaviour, at least currently.

Comment: @MichaelBurr "_but doesn't allow 're-aliasing'_" there is no "re-aliasing", and these rules say nothing about pointer conversions. The aliasing rules are rules about **uses of lvalues**.

Comment: @hvd "_the documentation for Wstrict-aliasing=2 promised to warn for all possible aliasing violations_" all possible violations? That is just preposterous. They could not possibly mean that, or they are just incompetent and unable to write a compiler.

Comment: @curiousguy And as it turns out, they didn't mean that. That's why the documentation was fixed.

Comment: @curiousguy: I understand I was being imprecise, which was why 're-aliasing' was in quotes.  Still, what I said doesn't contradict you, though you state it more precisely and clearly, I think.  But, don't forget, we aren't only discussing the standard's rules, but the behavior of GCC's warnings as well. And the second point was about how casts through a `char*` might affect those.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your example to produce a warning about breaking the strict-aliasing rules:

```
void foo(int* pi) {
    short* j = (short*)pi;
    j[0] = j[1] = 0;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1234;

    foo(&i);

    short* j = (short*)&i;
    j[0] = j[1] = 0;
}
```

Even though, g++ 4.6 only shows the warning if you compile the code with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` instead of `-Wstrict-aliasing`. Also, it only shows the warning for the cast in  `main()`, not in `foo()`. But I cannot see how/why the compiler would look at those two casts differently.

Comment: Whats the difference with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` and `-Wstrict-aliasing`?

Comment: @user1086635: Supposedly the three levels of strict-aliasing detection have increasingly low false positive rates through more detailed analysis of the code. 1 is the 'worst' level with the highest false positive rate, and 3 is the 'best' level with the lowest false positive rate. In playing around with the levels myself, it seems that 3 also has a high false negative rate.

Comment: "_But I cannot see how/why the compiler would look at those two casts differently._" Because in `main` the compiler knows the declared type of the variable.

Comment: @user1086635: Here is the current documentation for the -Wstrict-aliasing warning: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstrict_002daliasing_003dn-347